# Ethercamp. Could not start sandbox: Sandbox is not available

Tags: ether-camp, ethereum-studio

I somehow managed to break my ether-camp IDE. The sandbox wont' start. When clicking "Run All Contracts" it fails with `Could not start sandbox: Sandbox is not available`.

When browsing the filesystem, `/root/ethereum-sandbox` is still there and I didn't tamper with it.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same sandbox issue where it was not getting started. In my case it turned out that since I was working from behind a proxy, it was getting blocked. Trying to run the contract from an open network solved the problem.

You can post issues in [ether camp's](https://ether-camp-friends.slack.com/messages/ethereum-studio/) Slack. The support is great.